# Add annotations to heatmap with python3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, heatmap

I created a heatmap using matplotlib and seaborn, It looks ok.

But my question is how to add values on heatmap. My current heatmap contains only different colors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':index, 'y':colonnes, 'z':score})
data = data.pivot(index='x', columns='y', values='z')
sns.heatmap(data)
plt.show()
```

Any idea please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sns.heatmap(data, annot=True)
```

From documentation:

> annot : bool or rectangular dataset, optional. If True, write the data value in each cell. If an array-like with the same shape as data, then use this to annotate the heatmap instead of the raw data.

Also, play around with `fmt` and `annot_kws` paramaters.